# Swift scroller not scrolling

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a Swift code

```
    background_img_view.addSubview(background_image)
    background_img_view.addSubview(usn)
    profile_view.addSubview(PostsDiv)
    profile_view.addSubview(PostDiv)
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1500)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    scrollView.addSubview(profile_view)
    view.addSubview(background_img_view)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

I test this on my phone and scroller is showing,but when i scroll nothing changes,also i can't click on anything on the screen

Comment: What is the size of the scrollview? If the scrollview is bigger than its `contentSize` then it won't scroll.

Comment: @Sulthan are you talking about height?

Comment: Yes. I don't see you setting the frame. The easiest solution to debug this is printing the scrollview in your `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: @Sulthan `print(scrollView.frame.size.height)` returns 568.0

Comment: Are you sure none of your views has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to `false`? Are you sure there is not any other view (e.g. transparent) on top of your controller? If this is inside a controller, are you sure the controller is properly added/presented?

Comment: @Sulthan i have a textview inside `background_img_view` which's `isUserInteractionEnabled ` is set to `false`

Comment: Try to set `profile_view.userInteractionEnabled = false`. Maybe the contents of the scrollview are stealing your events.

Comment: @Sulthan here is my full code if this could be any help for you http://pastebin.com/EXQeGMJ6

Comment: Any gesture recognizers on profile_view?

Comment: @Sam_M 4 of them

Comment: @Sulthan i tried it,nothing changed

Comment: Ugh, when will people learn to use storyboards...

Comment: @Sulthan i hate storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are anchoring everything to the bottom of the background image but the background image is not in the scroll view so nothing moves when you scroll.

You need to replace `view.addSubview(background_img_view)` with `scrollView.addSubview(background_img_view)`

You also need to change the top anchor of the background image view and the background image to the top of the scrollView.

Replace:

```
background_img_view.anchor(view.topAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: about.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 60, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 280)
background_image.anchor(view.topAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 60, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 280)
```

With

```
background_img_view.anchor(scrollView.topAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: about.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 60, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 280)
background_image.anchor(scrollView.topAnchor, left:view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 60, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 280)
```

Comment: @BrunoSnickers Try adding this line to your code after setting the content size: `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true`

Comment: @BrunoSnickers Can you provide a link to your project?

Comment: How can i do that? Perhaps i can send you it in email?

Comment: @BrunoSnickers After trying your code I see that the scrolling works but the content is not moving. That's because you are anchoring everything to the bottom of background image but the background image is not in the scroll view so nothing moves when you scroll. Do you want the background image to move when scrolling or not?

Comment: Yes i do want it to move

Comment: Thank you really really really really much!